# Having trouble merging/consolidating date columns across dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, date, lambda, mask

I have the following dataframe (features):

```
         date  NZD Curncy      date.1  AUD Curncy      date.2  BBDXY Index  
0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN   
1  1971-01-04      1.1138  1971-01-04      1.1127  2004-12-31      1000.00   
2  1971-01-05      1.1143  1971-01-05      1.1132  2005-01-03      1005.03   
3  1971-01-06      1.1151  1971-01-06      1.1140  2005-01-04      1018.29   
4  1971-01-07      1.1150  1971-01-07      1.1138  2005-01-05      1018.44
```

and I am trying to consolidate the dates so it looks like:

```
         date  NZD Curncy  AUD Curncy   BBDXY Index  
0         NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN         
1  1971-01-04      1.1138  1.1127       NaN
2  1971-01-05      1.1143  1.1132       NaN
3  1971-01-06      1.1151  1.1140       NaN   
4  1971-01-07      1.1150  1.1138       NaN
```

I have tried to use:

```
s = features.columns.to_series()
mask = features.columns.duplicated(keep=False)
c = np.where(mask, s + '_'  + (s.groupby(s).cumcount() + 1).astype(str) , s)
features.columns = c

dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).dropna() 
       for i, x in features.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1)]


df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df2)
```

But I keep getting:

```
<ipython-input-32-78f4ed2d5cb3> in <lambda>(x)
      6 
      7 dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).dropna() 
----> 8        for i, x in features.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1)]
      9 
     10 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

A set of helpful eyes would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating a new df every second column and appending then looping through, I hope this helps someone else.

features in original question turned to df1 so I could keep features as an output

```
number_of_columns = len(df1.columns)

# store the split dataframes in a list
split_dfs = []

# loop over column indexes with step size 2
for i in range(0, number_of_columns, 2):
    split_dfs.append(df1.iloc[:, [i,i+1]])

#Merge all dataframes on date
number_of_dfs = len(split_dfs)

for i in range(0,number_of_dfs):
    split_dfs[i].rename(columns={split_dfs[i].columns[0]:'date'},inplace=True)
    
    
#create our features df
#Could have used functools, which I just learned about but had some NA issues so looped it
features = split_dfs[0]

for i in range(1,number_of_dfs):
    features = pd.merge(features,split_dfs[i], how='inner', on='date').dropna()
```